# One to One Mapping Clarification

Tags: hibernate

I have two tables

1. Employee Table
2. Address Table

Employee Table hbm definition will have the following

```
<id name="empGkey" column="primarykey" type="java.lang.Long" unsaved-value="null">
       <generator class="native"/>
   </id>
<many-to-one name="empAddress" column="address" class="com.region.Address"
cascade="all" unique="false"> </many-to-one>
```

Address Table hbm definition will have the following

```
<id name="addressGkey" column="primarykey" type="java.lang.Long" unsaved-value="null">
       <generator class="native"/>
   </id>
   <one-to-one name="addressEmp" class="com.region.Employee" property-ref="empAddress">
   </one-to-one>
```

Currently the application throws the following exception when execute the following HQL query

```
from Address where primarykey = '1232';

More than one row with the given identifier was found: 1232, for class: 
com.region.Employee (compact stack trace follows) 
org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load
(AbstractEntityLoader.java:92)
```

Clarification

```
1. Will Address primary key will always have one similar primary key in 
   Employee?
2. Will the Address primary key might differs from Employee primary key 
   column
3. Will the Address primary key will always have one similar address column
   value in Employee table?
4. When this issue might come?
5. How to fix the problem
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be problem in your hibernate configuration.
Employee is referring to address as many to one:

Where as on Address side you are referring Employee as one-to-one

Could you please confirm what exactly is your requirement?

Comment: Please refer hibernate in action page number 221. Many to one is really a one-to-one. We have defined so that it works properly. Can u please go through the PDF 221 for more info - https://www.cpe.ku.ac.th/~plw/oop/e_book/hibernate_in_action.pdf

Comment: Nice reference.Thanks!